# What should I use to build a parrilla?

Tags: meat, grilling

Basically, I just need the grate. From what material should it be made, to make it food safe?
Any idea how I can obtain it in a reasonable price?

Per Wikipedia (emphasis added):
Asado (Spanish: [aˈsaðo], Brazilian Portuguese: [assado]) is a term used both for a range of barbecue techniques and the social event of having or attending a barbecue[1] in Argentina (where it is considered the national dish),[2] Brazil, Chile, Colombia, Paraguay and Uruguay. In these countries, asado is a traditional dish and also the standard word for "barbecue". An asado usually consists of beef alongside various other meats, which are cooked on a grill, called a **parrilla**, or an open fire.

Comment: Possibly this should go to DIY?

Comment: http://www.fornobravo.com/forum/attachments/38/33097d1354986672-argentinian-parrilla-wood-charcoal-grill-parilla-1.jpg  -- Picture of a parilla; just looks like an open hearth grill

Comment: I'd guess the traditional material is iron. Probably a reasonable choice, if you can keep it dry.

Comment: This is *not* a good fit for DIY, if I got their rules correctly. They are about keeping your home in order, not about building new devices. Not sure about closing - on the one hand, it is once removed from actual food preparation, on the other hand, we accept questions on equipment.

Comment: @rumtscho: They list "carpentry and woodworking" on their [about page](http://diy.stackexchange.com/about), so... maybe? Although it's clear that their focus is on appliances and home repair/renovation, so even if it's on topic, it might not get great answers. *(I don't think it'll get great answers here either, for the record)*

Comment: As rumtscho said, we take questions about equipment, and "what's the traditional material for a parrilla grate?" is as reasonable a basic equipment question as "what materials are nonstick coatings made out of?" That said, I'm not sure if someone telling you "yup it's iron" as derobert guessed is going to help you much, and we can't really tell you where to buy materials locally if you're trying to build it yourself. (And if you have follow-up metalworking questions, those would definitely not be on-topic here.)

Comment: Not metal working per se, but is Iron food-safe? Can I cook on it with no worries, assuming it has no paint on it.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka it is certainly food-safe, as evidenced by the large number of cast iron pans produced and used around the world. It will indeed leach some iron into your food, but with iron being a trace element, you are more likely to benefit from it than to get poisoned, unless you are already close to the max dose from other sources, which is statistically highly unlikely. Iron deficiency is much more common today than iron overdose.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

Buy a grate that is mean for a grill that is the size you are making your parrilla. Usually you can find square cast iron grates for not too expensive and if you need a bigger surface, design your grill in multiplies of the size grate you choose.

You haven't mentioned the brick work, but make sure you use fire bricks for anything that will be exposed to the heat of the grill.

Comment: Was not so easy to find the right type of grill. Asado is done on a V shaped grill (Each "wire" is V shaped, not the entire thing), which allows the fat to flow away from the fire, and comparatively small gaps between each V. Both are designed to prevent from direct contact of fire and meat.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka These http://www.amazon.com/Weber-7527-Stainless-Replacement-Cooking/dp/B000WEMG4W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1368454264&sr=8-1&keywords=v+grate might work.

Comment: :-) Looks like I am getting annoyed by the small details, but, unless I am mistaken, the flow of fat is blocked at the end by the supporting beam (or how would u call this?). But now I know to google with "V grate" and I find good results - Thanks!

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka if you can't find anything you like, then getting a local craftsman to weld you one from cast iron shouldn't be a problem. Just make sure to season it properly (the same way you'd season a cast iron pan).

Comment: English is not my language, would I search for "Blacksmith" or something else?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka find me in chat and I can help you look if you'd like http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan